# setting currentSchema using URL for DB2 in AS400

Tags: database, hibernate, url, jdbc, db2

With DB2 JDBC type 4 driver (com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver), the URL to use in the configuration to connect to a DB2 database is: jdbc:db2://HOST:PORT/DATABASE:currentSchema=SCHEMA; this is working perfectly fine with mainframes database.

But what is the URL to connect to a database on AS400 using the driver 'com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver'... 'currentSchema' included in the URL, is not working in this case. The username is being considered as the name of the schema. How do I set current schema using URL?

Comment: i got it... we need to use 'libraries' instead of 'currentSchema' in case of AS400...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the as400 sub-protocol, and specify your default like this

```
jdbc:as400://hostname/default-schema
```

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21398042

Comment: This works if that is the only schema we want to use from the database. But if we specify a default schema, we wont be able to switch to other schemas. Using this will allow us to switch between various schemas in the same database. jdbc:db2://HOST:PORT/DATABASE:libraries=SCHEMA;